# Find SQLite Database On WinRT

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime

When my application starts I can copy a pre-populated SQLite database to the application LocalFolder as suggested here (http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/06/28/seeding-your-metro-style-app-with-sqlite-database.aspx).

Now I would like to be able to get a copy of the database back at times when debugging so I can inspect its contents and check that it is as expected.  Is there anyway to do this when using the simulator, or even when running local if not ?

Thannk you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be located SOMEWHERE under:

```
C:\Users\<your-username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<your-application-package>\LocalState\
```

Both the simulator and the local application use this same location for storage.