# sqlite database location uwp

Tags: c#, sqlite, database-connection, win-universal-app

I have an uwp app with a sqlite database that works as intended; I can close the program and restart it and the database is loaded properly. I want to look at the database with a database viewer but can't locate the file. I have tried unhiding files and searching for db.sqlite. Here is the code that connects to the database:

```
string path;
SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn;
path =Path.Combine
(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,"db.sqlite");
conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new
SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find SQLite Database On WinRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318931/find-sqlite-database-on-winrt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to

> C:\Users\[YourUserName]\AppData\Local\Packages\

your application will have its own folder there, which you may be able to recognise by name or do a search for sqlite, and the SQLite database file should be within your applications folder

Comment: Thank you! The application name was completely different and I found with search.

Answer (score 8):

> C:\Users[Your User Name]\AppData\Local\Packages[Your Package Name]\LocalState

Your Package Name: You can find in file Package.appxmanifest in your Project
Your file db.sqlite will in folder **LocalState**